# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rent')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to proceed to an order test I've defined sub steps order but I really don't know what's going on before getting this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rent')`.
I have `OrderForm` interface which is my shape of Order looks like:

```
export interface OrderForm {
  model_id?: number;
  model_color_id?: number;
  model_product_id?: number;
  batteries_id?: number;
  accessories?: Array<SelectedAccessory>;
  number_of_batteries?: number;
  delivery_option_id?: number;
  withdrawal_site_id?: number;
  delivery_address?: UserAddress;
  order_amount: number;
  paymentOptions?: OrderPaymentOptions;
  total_lld: ComputedTotalLLDOptions;
  product_parts_id?: string;
}
```

and this interface as well

```
// Index is the number of months
// All prices are stored in cts
export interface ComputedTotalLLDOptions {
  [index: number]: {
    contribution: number;
    duration: number;
    rent: number;
  };
}
```

So, I'm using in my tsx file called finance.tsx like this:

```
<Box pl={4}>
   <Typography component="div" variant="body1">
     <DepositToday amount={deposit} />
        <Box display="flex" alignItems="baseline" flexWrap="wrap">
          <MonthlyPayment
             prefix={t("summary.financing.long_term_rental_prefix")}
             suffix={t("summary.financing.long_term_rental_suffix")}
             amount={order.total_lld[duration].rent / 100}
        />
                &nbsp;
       <CashPrice
            prefix={t("summary.financing.long_term_rental_body", {
                duration: duration - 1,
                  })}
            amount={
                    (order.total_lld[duration].contribution +
                      order.total_lld[duration].rent) /
                    100
                  }
                />
  </Box>
```

When I open my log browser I have this error:

[image: Error message]

Comment: use `order.total_lld[duration]?.rent` see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Well, clearly `order.total_lld[duration]` is undefined. Use a null check/guard clause or Optional Chaining operator. Or fix the data and rendering logic so it's not rendering until all the data is ready.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, keep in mind that interfaces are *types* for us to "see". They are very useful, but they are only used for us, developers. The actual javascript ran in the engine should also have the same shape, but if you make some mistake(s) in your code, it *might* not have that shape at all.

Regarding the exception, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '[attribute]')`, it always means the same thing: you are trying to read `undefined.attribute`.

So in your case, `order.total_lld[duration]` is not an object, it is `undefined`. when you try to read `order.total_lld[duration].rent`, you are actually reading `undefined.rent`, throwing the exception.

With the code provided, it is impossible to determine where the problem is.
I suggest you use the debugger tools (or some `console.log`s, if it is easier for you), and check what is the actual value of `order.total_lld` and `duration`. One of them (or both) are incorrect.

Comment: I use optional chaining like this `order.total-lld[duration]?.rent`  and it worked :)